# Dynamic Excel report 2010 against MS analysis services Cube using parameters

Tags: excel, reporting-services, excel-2007, ssas

I have to create dynamic excel 2010 report.

Data will come from Cube. there will be a parameter : **YEAR**

Based on that select year, data will be presented. Should be look like this.

---

Select Year : 2000- 2012 (any one of them)         **Refresh Button**

---

```
    Account  Name  Amount   Address   Country
```

---

1

2

3

---

User can select any year and just click on refresh button he should get related year data.

I am new with excel reporting , please help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: What did you already try? What does the data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you [connect your work book to SSAS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940167) you can go to the "Data" ribbon and click on the "Existing Connections" button.  Click on the connection for your Cube and click open.

You should get a window like this:

[image]

If you choose "PivotTable Report" then you'll get a Pivot table where you can drag and drop your fields to look like your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing. Is it possible if user select one year (2010) and all months will be split into columns in the reports. Jan to dec.

Comment: Not easily in 2007.  In 2010 you can link a control called a slicer to the field but in 2007 you would need to have your date dimension in the column field.  You can't have it both in a filter field and a column field.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on 2010 excel. Can you tell me a bit more slicer.

Comment: Here's an article from MS on slicers:  http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/09/23/easy-and-even-fun-data-exploration-introducing-excel-2010-slicers.aspx